# Can you use imul to multiply a register by itself?

Tags: assembly, x86

Making a assembly program to calculate exponents - can I use the imul instuction with the same register as both operands?

Comment: Yes, and it worked. However I wasn't sure if it works in all cases or if it was even best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. `imul ax,ax` is a perfectly good instruction.

> ELSE IF (NumberOfOperands = 2)
>   THEN
>   temp ← DEST ∗ SRC (* Signed multiplication; temp is double DEST size *)
>
>   DEST ← DEST ∗ SRC (* Signed multiplication *)
>   IF temp ≠ DEST
>   THEN CF ← 1; OF ← 1;
>   ELSE CF ← 0; OF ← 0; FI;

As you can see from the operational algorithm, there's no risk of corrupting the single register *while the multiplication occurs* since the CPU uses a *temp* while multiplying. CF and OF are set if this *temp* doesn't fit in the single register.

Comment: I downvoted this earlier, but didn't have time to leave the reason. Your intervening edit is much better, but for me to finally remove the the downvote, could you at least let the original poster know that he should consult an instruction set reference. You could provide a link to the Intel documentation, but I find [Felix Coultier's web version](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) of the Intel references easier to navigate.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Phrases like "Look it up in the manual" and "Learn to use a debugger" (another classic) make for very good comments but don't do it so well in an answer. Concerning providing a link, I believe the majority of people asking questions already has the documentation/instruction set reference at their disposal, but for some reason just can't extract the relevant pieces, hence I provided an excerpt with some clarification.